# Injecting custom CSS to override specific object formats - advice

Tags: html, css, blogger

Newbie here. I'm re-learning web on HTML5 - customizing a blogger site to cut-my-teeth.  I've been able to change a lot from the defaults (w3schools is invaluable!) but I'm getting stuck when trying to change formats for **specific** objects.

Three things I can't figure out as examples (site www.paddlebeforethewave.com)

1) Featured Post (top) - image wrapping text is a default behavior for blog posts that isn't followed for featured post. I was able to change the image/size position as below - but can't figure out how to have text wrap the image.

```
.FeaturedPost .snippet-thumbnail img {
  max-width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline;
}
```

2) Featured post (top) - I want to change background color of only the featuredpost.  I've tried to identify and modify it as follows - but no effect.

```
.Blog .blog-posts .post-outer-container, #page_body .FeaturedPost {
  background: $(posts.background.color);
  min-height: 40px;
 padding: 30px 40px;
 width: auto;
}
```

OR

```
.FeaturedPost .bgcolor {
   background-color: #cfe2f3;
}
```

OR 
    many permutations of above

3) Page 2 content - I created a second page (http://www.paddlebeforethewave.com/p/contact.html) and the formatting is lost for vertical padding and location of page labels.

Is my approach flawed? Could you use one fix as example (I want to learn!)

thank you!

[Screenshot for (1) and (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3ZtN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add the following code to your theme:

```
.FeaturedPost .snippet-thumbnail,
.FeaturedPost .post-snippet {
    display: inline;
}
```

2) Your approach is fine, if you haven't seen any changes, try to clear your browser cache. Correct classes for featured post are:

```
.Blog .post-outer-container, #page_body .FeaturedPost {
 }
```

3) I'm not sure I can see the problem. Could you provide a screenshot, please?

EDIT:

Found it! Go to your theme code and add following property to this class:

```
.item-view .blog-name {
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    flex-flow: column;
}
```

Comment: thank you Luca!   The color change did work with background-color: #cdf2ee; within the class.

Answer (score 0):

I see you fixed your problem I did however see an issue on your site. For big screens a white bar appears if the screen is larger than 1800px.

[image]

You can fix this by finding this code in your CSS

```
.sidebar-container
```

and adding

```
display:none;
```

[image]

You could test this in your browser by zooming out until the bar appears. Cheers

Comment: thank you for this!  I didn't know how to fix this - now resolved!

Comment: Nice no problem